# span generated using jQuery does not autofocus lighbox image

Tags: jquery, html, lightbox

I have a jQuery code that generates a lightbox span upon drop-down menu change. My goal was to show the image on change of the drop-down menu and be able to click on the image so that the lightbox will show on the screen.

The issue that I'm running into is that when I change the drop-down menu, the image shows, but the lightbox requires double-click to open.

I figured that it was because the drop-down menu has focus and the lightbox image needs focus first, before it can be clickable.

One solution is for me to automatically pass focus to the lightbox, so that on drop-down change the lightbox image has focus already and only requires one click. However, I wish I didn't lose focus automatically from the drop-down because there may be users that will like to navigate the drop-down via keyboard up/down arrows.

One thing that I noticed is that if I have the span static in the HTML, this problem does not happen. My guess is that it's not anything with the focus, but rather the span getting created on-the-fly. I haven't found a solution to overcome this but I'm running out of ideas. Anyone has any suggestions on what I should be looking for or manuals that I can look at to further adjust the code?

Here is a simplified Codepen sampe: https://codepen.io/speedygonzales77/pen/jOOZJLJ

```
           if ( (preferred_facility == 'Classroom (laboratory)') && (label == 'BRYAN CAMPUS') ) {


          $('.img_link').html('<a data-lightbox="blinn-gallery" data-title="" href="https://www.blinn.edu/_facilities-listing-demo/images/facilities/bryan/800/classroom-laboratory.jpg"><img alt="Classroom (laboratory)" class="img-thumbnail" height="200" src="https://www.blinn.edu/_facilities-listing-demo/images/facilities/bryan/800/classroom-laboratory.jpg" width="300"></a>');


        }
```

Comment: What I have seen is that you have to click twice in order to show the big picture. Is that your issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Try my fork of youy pen :
I choose to update the src and href attributes, not to rewrite the whole html
https://codepen.io/phmmeyer/pen/xxxWOMg

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
 let brianCampusImages = [
   {label:"student-center-f-140",image:"https://www.blinn.edu/_facilities-listing-demo/images/facilities/bryan/800/student-center-f-140.jpg"},
    {label:"Classroom (laboratory)",image:"https://www.blinn.edu/_facilities-listing-demo/images/facilities/bryan/800/classroom-laboratory.jpg"}
 ]

$("#preferred_facility").on("change",function(){
  let offset = parseInt($(this).val())
  let zone = $("#blinn-gallery-zone");
  $(zone)
    .find("a")
    .attr("href",brianCampusImages[offset].image);

    $(zone)
    .find("img")
    .attr("src",brianCampusImages[offset].image)
    .attr("alt",brianCampusImages[offset].label);

  setTimeout(function(){
    zone.css("display","inline-block")
  },500);
});
```

Comment: Hi PhilMaGeo. Your solution works great. I'll need to find a way to fit it with the rest of the code that I have in production, but your tweak does what I was looking for.

Comment: I happy it helped you :-)